# convert ArrayList<Class> to string[]

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have class Person

```
class person{
int ID ;
sting FirstName ;
string Last Name ;
String Telephone ;

}
```

and I have `ArrayList<person> ;`

now I want to display simple list view containing just `FirstName + "," + "LastName"`

so I can use  code  like

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Color Mode");

ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

builder.setView(modeList);
final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

dialog.show();
```

so how to cconvert the ArrayList to string[] that contains the format `FirstName + "," + "LastName"`

I can loop , but Is there any good way or simple way to do that , because I tried to use adapter but it failed to appear in the dialoge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `ArrayAdapter` to use the type `person` and not `String` (also, just pass the `ArrayList<person>` instead of an array) like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<person> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, theArrayList);
```

and then override the `person`'s class `toString` method:

```
class person {
        int ID;
        String FirstName;
        String LastName;
        String Telephone;

        @Override
        public String toString() {          
            return "Whatever " + FirstName + " and Whatever  " + LastName;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wooow , it like invention , u saved me really , so fast too

Comment: now I have listview I display on dialoge after click button , Iwant when click on item of list , fill anothe control with the textview , it always crash any idea

Comment: @AMH You should ask another question and provide the full code that you use plus the log with the exception you get.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281978/fill-control-after-click-list

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Custom Adapter. Here you do not need to convert ArrayList to String ArrayList. You able to set data via array-list position.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995840/populating-listview-by-passing-multiple-arraylists-through-custom-baseadapter)

Thanks