# Fill control after click list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I have layout like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_OK"
        android:layout_width="400dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_patientNOK"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_Continue"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:text="show" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the code look like

```
Button Show;
EditText    et_OK;
String[] stringArray;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    // define the Data 
     View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.searchmainscreen,
                container,
                false);

this.et_OK = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_OK));
 this.Show= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_show);
        this.Show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Select Color Mode");

                    ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
                     stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
                    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
                    modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                              int position, long id) {

                    FillControl(position) ;
                 }});

                    builder.setView(modeList);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

                    dialog.show();



            }
        });

     return view;
}
public void FillControl(int Postion)
{
    /*
     *  TextView Result ; 

Button Continue ;
Button Clear;

EditText       

            NOK ;
CheckBox Registered ; 

// 1 regi
 * 
     * 
     * */


    Log.d(" the arrayaaaaaaaa"," the array is has "+  PatientSearchResult.size() + "With Postion" + Postion);

    String test  = stringArray[Postion] ; 

    et_OK.settext(test); // it crash here 






}


}
```

it raise error

```
07-01 15:12:10.860: D/the arrayaaaaaaaa(32020):  the array is has 18With Postion4
07-01 15:12:10.860: W/ResourceType(32020): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00002736
07-01 15:12:10.860: D/AndroidRuntime(32020): Shutting down VM
07-01 15:12:10.860: W/dalvikvm(32020): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4023f760)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2736
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:238)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3229)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.appnetics.PatientSearch.FillControl(PatientSearch.java:336)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.appnetics.PatientSearch$3.onItemClick(PatientSearch.java:293)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1148)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2643)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3466)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3805)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4640)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1881)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1296)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:720)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1854)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4708)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2448)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2109)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-01 15:12:10.880: E/AndroidRuntime(32020):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 15:17:16.430: I/Process(32020): Sending signal. PID: 32020 SIG: 9
07-01 15:17:20.440: D/CLIPBOARD(32199): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-01 15:17:31.575: D/dalvikvm(32199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 4% free 6655K/6919K, paused 20ms
07-01 15:17:37.000: D/dalvikvm(32199): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 4% free 6938K/7175K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-01 15:17:37.940: D/EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE(32199): Am here wanna play
07-01 15:17:38.130: D/the arrayaaaaaaaa(32199):  the array is has 18
07-01 15:17:38.145: D/the arrayaaaaaaaa(32199):  the array is has 18
07-01 15:17:38.145: D/EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE(32199): 18
07-01 15:17:38.145: D/EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE(32199): Am here wanna play 123
07-01 15:17:38.185: D/dalvikvm(32199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 367K, 8% free 6984K/7559K, paused 35ms
07-01 15:17:38.185: I/dalvikvm-heap(32199): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.379MB for 513744-byte allocation
07-01 15:17:38.215: D/dalvikvm(32199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 7485K/8071K, paused 17ms
07-01 15:17:38.275: D/dalvikvm(32199): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 6% free 7605K/8071K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-01 15:17:39.625: D/the arrayaaaaaaaa(32199):  the array is has 18With Postion3
07-01 15:17:39.625: W/ResourceType(32199): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00002734
07-01 15:17:39.625: D/AndroidRuntime(32199): Shutting down VM
07-01 15:17:39.625: W/dalvikvm(32199): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4023f760)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2734
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:238)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3229)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.appnetics.PatientSearch.FillControl(PatientSearch.java:336)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.appnetics.PatientSearch$3.onItemClick(PatientSearch.java:293)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1148)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2643)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3466)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3805)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4640)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1881)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1296)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:720)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1854)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4708)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2448)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2109)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-01 15:17:39.645: E/AndroidRuntime(32199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any idea how to fix that

Comment: just clean project from Project-Clean... on Eclipse IDE

Comment: To me error seems to be somewhere else.post complete code

Comment: @VipulShah this is the complete code

Comment: @imrankhan I cleaned the code but the same issue

Comment: make sure your listview id is as android:id="@id/android:list"

Comment: @imrankhan I don't have lsit I create it or run time

Comment: @AMH : try after change et_OK.settext(test) to et_OK.settext(String.valueOf(test))

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown at that line? Could you add the full exception stacktrace and not just the first 3 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Change as

```
String test  = stringArray[Postion] ;
```

to

```
String test  = String.valueOf(stringArray[Postion]) + "" ; 

et_OK.setText(test);
```

Comment: then put a log before et_OK.setText(test); as Log.v("Test value",test); and check value of test varaible

Comment: and also clean & rebuild the project  after changing to et_OK.setText(test);

Comment: check log using Log.v("Test value",test);

Comment: use  et_OK instead this.et_OK maybe creating problem

Comment: I did the same thing I make sure it entered the function because I used Log.d() and it whoed in the log

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think ?

```
 et_OK.settext(test); // it crash here
```

Shoud be

```
 et_OK.setText(test);
```

Comment: clean & rebuild the project and see!!

Comment: I make sure it entered the function because I used Log.d() and it whoed in the log –

Answer (score 0):

first comment that two line for getting string and setting to edittext before this check

```
 Log.d("length",""+stringArray.length());
```

if it is not equal to 0 than we can go ahead for set text or other thing

Comment: no it work very well, no problem in all except the filling part of contorols