# Android: passing string into ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a spinner and i am dynamically loading the spinner with messages 
i am doing it as below

```
protected List<Message> messages = null;
ArrayAdapter <Message> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>( activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,messages);               

                       spinner1.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

i am getting the message as below

```
public List<Message> getMessages(String type) throws Exception{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod get = null;
    Message message = null;
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    try {
        get = new GetMethod("http://" + Constants.CLOUD_SERVER_URL + Constants.getMessages + "/"+type);
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(get);
        if(statusCode == 200){
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully posted the comments");
            Utils utils = new Utils();
            Document doc = utils.formatInputStream(get.getResponseBodyAsStream());
            NodeList listMessages = doc.getElementsByTagName("message");
            int totalMessage = listMessages.getLength();
            for (int s = 0; s < totalMessage; s++) {
                Node messageNode = listMessages.item(s);
                if (messageNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element messageElement = (Element) messageNode;
                    message = new Message();
                    message.setId(utils.getTagValue(messageElement, "id"));
                    message.setMessage(utils.getTagValue(messageElement, "question"));
                    messages.add(message);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Id - " + message.getId() + " Message - " + message.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Either server has problem or not reachable at this time");
            throw new Exception("Server Issue Status code return by server is " + statusCode);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "recommend ----------> Step 15");
        Log.d(TAG, "recommend ----------> Step 20");
    }finally{
        get.releaseConnection();
        get = null;
    }
    return messages;
}
```

my issue is i am getting id of the message in spinner not the message text 
how to convert that message into string and pass it to adapter or 
any other way that finally i get the text in the spinner.

Comment: What are you passing to "messages"?

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah updated my question please look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to override `toString()` method of your `Message` class and return the message value like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return message; //where message is member variable holding message text
}
```

Comment: itz not allowing me to do...i edited my question ..please look at it

Comment: @njzk2    in my question i have a method which is returning messages how can i convert into string?

Comment: you have to override Message to include the toString method given by Waqas. Otherwise how do you expect the ArrayAdapter to know what you want it to put in the textview ? (alternate solution : put strings in your array)

Comment: @Waqas hi thank you now itz working i  override toString() in my message pojo class where my getters and setters arethere and itz working thxxx

Comment: @teekib nice that it helped :)

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281147/convert-arraylistclass-to-string